# Configure GDB to accept Cross-Compiled executables?

Tags: arm, gdb

I'm still a newbie to assembly language and cross-compiling etc. I've already googled the problem I'm having and seen a few similar posts but none of them solved my problem unfortunately.

We're learning ARM32 Syntax at the university and playing around with assembly code on AARCH64 machines on a uni server. So we need to cross-compile the .s files to be able to run them.
We use the command arm-linuxgnueabihf-gcc to cross-compile.
Now the system (the loader I guess) is configured properly to execute these 32-bit cross executables. When I tried to debug a 32b exec however GDB crashes with error: selected architecture armv7 is not compatible with reported target architecture aarch64

There are screenshots below that illustrate the problem. Thanks for any help!

System infos:
[System info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEwvC.png)

No error with native compiler:
[No error with native compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvpyk.png)

Error with cross-compilation:
[Error with cross-compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQLlz.png)

Comment: arm-whatever-gcc builds 32 bit arm programs not aarch64, you need to mate arm-whatever-gcc with a gdb built for aarch32.  you need aarch64-whatever-gcc with a gdb built for aarch64.  in the gnu world you cant cross those streams.

Comment: armv7a is 32 bit or aarch32 and it is also the aarch32 support within an armv8a based chip.  armv8a is aarch64, a completely incompatible instruction set from the aarch32.  now I dont know how multi isa environments are handled (running linux in 64 bit with aarch32 programs in the application layer).

Comment: Do you have a `arm-linuxgnueabihf-gdb` or `gdb-multi` command?

Comment: What is the 'uni server' running as its operating system/distribution ?.